# Adjoint ket vectors in Dirac notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, duality

In books on quantum physics you often see things like $\left(A|\Psi\rangle\right)^\dagger=\langle\Psi|A^\dagger$. However, $|\Psi\rangle:=\Psi\in\mathcal{H}$ is a vector and $\langle\Psi|:=\Psi^\ast\in\mathcal{H}^\ast$ is its dual counterpart, while $A$ is an operator, i.e. $A\in Aut(\mathcal{H})$. From what I understand, the property '*adjoint*' is only defined with respect to operators.

Let $A,B:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ be operators. Then $B=A^\dagger$, iff $\langle B\Psi,\Phi\rangle=\langle\Psi,A\Phi\rangle$ for all $\Psi,\Phi\in\mathcal{H}$.

Then how is $|\Psi\rangle^\dagger$ defined and justified as notation and why do we have $|\Psi\rangle^\dagger=\langle\Psi|$?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343910/is-a-bra-the-adjoint-of-a-ket)?

Comment: No, but it is of great help to me. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: You can view a bra as a linear functional that takes a vector in a hilbert space and gives you a number. There are bras that take a basis ket and spit out a number one for example...but for all the other basis kets, they spit zero. These make a dual basis in a dual space of these linear functionals. So this dual space is also a vector space.

Comment: Rigorously, let $\Psi \in H$ with $H$ a Hilbert space. Then $H^\star= \mathrm{Hom}(H,\mathbb{C})$ and $\Psi^\dagger \in H^\star$. In physics then we often dress the elements of $H$ and $H^\star$ as kets and bras without much gain actually.

Answer (score -1):

A vector is an arrow in spatial dimensions, it is not related to states in a hilbert space of the quantum mechanics. "Adjoint" is defined only in relation to the inner product of the states, not the operators.
What you make us of when writing things like $|\Psi\rangle^\dagger=\langle\Psi|$ is the inner product of your complex state space, which relates complex conjugacy to the symmetries of said inner product !

Comment: I'm afraid, that is actually wrong since a Hilbert space is a vector space in particular, i.e. its elements are vectors. But you are right: *adjointness* is defined with respect to the inner product of the vector space that the operators are defined on.

Comment: But the elements of a vector space are not vectors but states, a vector is just an arrow pointing at things in the real world

Comment: No, that's wrong. A vector space is concisely defined in mathematics:  [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html). The analogy to our space in reality makes sense for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard scalar product and the Euklidean norm. In quantum physics the span of a vector in a Hilbert space, i.e. a one-dimensional subspace of the Hilbert space is called a *state*.

Comment: But how should this be a vector, on what does this point in this Hilbert space ? You can't point to states !

Comment: @StringTheoretican You use a very nonstandard (confused) mathematical  terminology. The elements of a vector (or linear) space are called vectors. The states are actually vectors as well, in the continuous dual of the linear space of (bounded) observables. This means that observables are vectors as well. This is the standard mathematical terminology. For you "vector" refers to a translation or displacement vector in an affine space.

Comment: ok, thank you for enlighting  me there, I think I have to revisit my geometry course. So when we speak of stuff like manifolds we do not actually mean coordinate states but vectors ?

Comment: A manifold is a linear space locally, yes.

Comment: A manifold is actually a topological space with some added structure to it..

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić Not all manifolds are endowed with a topological structure...and a topological space need not in general to be a linear space (and "interesting" manifolds are in fact not linear spaces globally, but only locally).

Comment: So a manifold does not need to be a topological space?

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić it is not necessary, even if most manifolds are considered with an endowed topology. Of course without it there are very few things that one can do, but still it is a definable object.

Comment: Ok, I have been learning about manifolds for a month or so now in the context of physics and it was always a topological space with a structure of smoothness defined upon it. It is sad that manifold looks locally like Euclidean space also. So what is a precise mathematical definition of a manifold?

Comment: http://web.stanford.edu/~jchw/WOMPtalk-Manifolds.pdf

Comment: In almost all the books this is how they define it...

Comment: In order to talk about a manifold you need a topology otherwise we can talk about a set being open or not. And this is exactly what comes in the definition of a manifold. At each point the tangent space of a manifold can be equipped with vector space operations.

Comment: @yuggib How do you define a manifold if not as a topological space?

Comment: @d_b I think "manifold" is more of a concept than a precise mathematical object (if no other specification is attached). Smooth manifolds are indeed topological spaces, but algebraic varieties, orbifolds, and homological manifolds may not be. Still, they are considered kinds of manifolds (or generalized manifolds, if you prefer).

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't seen manifold used in that way. I guess I would prefer the more generic "space," but I can imagine sometimes that is *too* generic.